# Convert a string date format from "17-Nov-2011" to "11/17/11"

Tags: ruby, date, formatting

I have this code that converts an array of date strings from a format of 17-Nov-2011 to 11/17/11:

```
def date_convert dates
  months = { 'Jan' => 1, 'Feb' => 2, 'Mar' => 3, 'Apr' => 4, 
             'May' => 5, 'Jun' => 6, 'Jul' => 7, 'Aug' => 8, 
             'Sep' => 9, 'Oct' => 10, 'Nov' => 11, 'Dec' => 12 }
  new_dates = []
  dates.each do |date|
    date_split = date.split('-')
    month = months[date_split[1]] 
    day = date_split[0]
    year = date_split[2][-2, 2]
    new_dates.push ("#{month}/#{day}/#{year}")
  end
  new_dates
end
```

Is there a better, possibly built in, way to make this conversion with Ruby? I am learning Ruby so any other approach to this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ruby's [`Date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) and [`Time`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/index.html) libraries are very full featured. Both deserve taking the time to get to know what they can do; Date handles greater ranges than Time.

Comment: For times when `parse` fails or gets confused, you should explicitly look at [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)

Comment: note: empty array + each + push = map

Comment: I will take a long look at `Date` and `Time` as well as `map` and `DateTie.strptime`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the built-in `Time.parse` and `Time#strftime` functions.

```
require 'time'
time = Time.parse("17-Nov-2011")
time.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
# => "11/17/11"
```

Comment: I'd chain `.strftime()` to the parse, but that's a minor difference.

Comment: using Time.parse... returned: undefined method `parse' for Time:Class (NoMethodError)?

Comment: I did not! That fixed it. Is there a difference/advantage to using `Time.parse` over `Date.parse` (it seems that with Date.parse I don't have to require anything)?

Comment: If you just need to work with dates, Date.parse is fine. However, I remember old version of Ruby didn't provide either `.parse` or `.strftime`. Ruby 1.9.2 does.

Answer (score 10):

With `Date#strftime` you can format a date. `Date.strptime` allows you a 'reverse' action: Build a date from string.

When you combine both, you get your result:

```
puts Date.strptime('17-Nov-2011', '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

Each `%`-Parameters is a part of the date string.
You need:

For parsing the date string:

- %d: number of the day (17)
- %b: Month with three letters (Nov)
- %Y: Year with 4 digits (2011)

For creating the string:

- %m: Month (11)
- %d: number of the day (17)
- %y: Year with 2 digits (11)

Comment: I knew Ruby could take a guess at how to parse a date string, but I didn't know you could tell it the format, which is exactly what I just needed to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ruby has a pretty robust set of date and time functions, check out the [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) class.

```
Date.parse("17-Nov-2011").strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```